# Is Every System of Linear Equations with Four Equations and Two Variables Inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is every system of linear equations with four equations and two variables inconsistent?

Comment: How about this one? $$\begin{cases}x=1\\y=1\\2x=2\\3y=3\end{cases}$$

Comment: I deleted my comment

Answer (score 1):

No, just take any system of two equations, then multiply one by $2$ and the other by $3$.  So $$x+y=2\\x-y=1\\2x+2y=4\\3x-3y=3$$ has solution $x=\frac 32, y=\frac 12$.  Even easier, take one equation and multiply it by $2,3,4$

Answer (score 0):

No. As an example, solve:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=3\\
x-y=1\\
2x+2y=6\\
3x-3y=3
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple necessary and sufficient condition for a linear system to be consistent: the matrix of the system and the augmented matrix have the same rank.

Furthermore, when the system is consistent, this rank is the codimension of the set of solutions (in affine space).