# Determine the value(s) of h such that the matrix is augmented matrix of a consistent linear system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I have this confusing question. I do not only need guidance in this question but I need a specific pattern which can help me solve these types of questions. If anyone would provide that, I would be grateful.

**The Augmented Form in this Question is:**
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&-3&h\\
      -2&6&-5
    \end{array}
\right] $$

**MY TRIES:**

***First Approach:***

1. $R_2\to2R_1+R_2$
2. $-5+2h=0\implies h=\frac{5}{2}$
3. Therefore, the linear system is consistent only when $h$ is $\frac{5}{2}$.

***Second Approach:***

If we look closely, the first two elements of the second row are $-2$ times the first two elements of the first row, therefore, the last element of the second row must be $-2$ times $h$ (that is the last element of the first row). This, can't be true because the last element of the second row is $-5$ which is not the multiple of $2$. Therefore, the linear system is inconsistent for all the values of $h$.

Now, I am confused that which approach should I follow and also I am not sure that even if these approaches are true or is there any other way? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your second approach is for a diophantine system of equations. Who told you $h$ has to be an integer?

Comment: Hi @Bernard I read it on Yahoo Answers, see this link
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110926211752AAoABOR

Comment: Well, it's false: in the example you link to, we can write  $\;2=-3\cdot-\dfrac23$.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, I was thinking the same but was not sure. Well, so which approach should I go for? The first one or the second one? And is the first approach correct? I meant, for me it's true according to the definition of a `marix` being `consistent`.

Comment: The first, undoubtedly (unless you're doing arithmetic, naturally). It's quite correct. For more complex situations, the criterion for consistency is this: the matrix of the l.h.s. of the linear system and the augmented matrix have the same rank.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks you so much. Can you post this as a answer so that I could select it and my questions get marked as 'Answered' for the other people?

Comment: I've already given this answer to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524718/is-every-system-of-linear-equations-with-four-equations-and-two-variables-incons/1524746#1524746) with information on the dimension of the space of solution.